# React native Text Input with Left and Right View mode

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to build a Search component with Textfield with both right view and left view(Images at both end). Text Input wraps itself to the length of the content, so component no covering entire parent width. How to stretch the component so that entire component occupies the full width of parent.

```
 <View
style={{
    flexDirection: "row",
    height: 40,
    alignSelf: "stretch",
    backgroundColor: "red"
}}
>
<Image
    source={require("./image_assets_rn/search_rn.png")}
    style={{ alignSelf: "center" }}
/>
<TextInput
    placeholder="Search Jet"
    style={{ backgroundColor: "white", alignSelf: "stretch" }}
/>
<Image
    source={require("./image_assets_rn/search_rn.png")}
    style={{ alignSelf: "center" }}
 />
</View>;
```

Below is the output. I want to stretch the textfield along the main axis(width)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved giving the `TextInput` `flex:1`, there is no need to use stretch.

```
  <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{flexDirection:'row', width: 300, height:40,backgroundColor:'lightgray'}}>
            <Image
                source={require('./image_assets_rn/search_rn.png')}
                style={{ height: 30, width: 20,margin: 5}}
            />
           <TextInput 
                placeholder="Search Jet" 
                style={{backgroundColor:'white', flex:1}}
            />
            <Image
                source={require('./image_assets_rn/search_rn.png')}
                style={{ height: 30, width: 20, margin:5}}
            />
            </View>
      </View>
```

Check it on [snack](https://snack.expo.io/B1JWCpyub)

I recommend you [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7D-0n1z1EbhkundIsOBaN_mlLvV4_hyO) to have a grasp on how flexbox works.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Interesting! Text input Supposed push away the second icon 

Answer (score 0):

I just add component flexbox in each component that wrapped in component `View`. I think it will make every component follow the parent width.

```
<View style={{ flexDirection:'row',
               height:40,
               alignSelf:'stretch',
               backgroundColor:'red' }}>

   <Image source={ require('./image_assets_rn/search_rn.png')} 
            style={{ flex:1, alignSelf:'center' }}/>

       <TextInput placeholder="Search Jet" 
              style={{ flex:1, backgroundColor:'white', 
                       alignSelf:'stretch' }}/>

   <Image source={ require('./image_assets_rn/search_rn.png')} 
              style={{ flex:1, alignSelf:'center' }}/>

</View>
```

If you want to learn more about `Flexbox` maybe you can read on the [Official Web ReactNative](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html).

I hope this can help you :))